# Lifetime declaration errors on struct with &str

Tags: rust

I have a struct like this -

```
pub struct A {
    pub f: &str,
}
```

When I later try to assign a &str value to the struct using this -

```
fn use(&self, t: &str){
       let a = A {
            f: self.t,
       };
}
```

I get an error saying -

```
pub f: &str,
  |      ^ expected named lifetime parameter
```

I then changed my struct to use named lifetime parameters -

```
pub struct A<'i> {
    pub f: &'i str,
}
```

But it now gives error -

```
implicit elided lifetime not allowed here

note: assuming a `'static` lifetime...
help: indicate the anonymous lifetime
```

Can someone explain the second error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post the full code that's generating that error; I can't reproduce your issue from what you've provided.

Comment: Storing `&x` references in structs is a bad idea 99% of the time. Consider using a `String` or `Box<str>` instead so the struct can *own* the data itself and not be dependent on a external lifetime that will limit how you can use the struct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String` instead of `&str`

```
pub struct A {
    pub f: String,
}

// use .to_string() to convert &str to String
fn use(&self, t: &str){
       let a = A {
            f: t.to_string(),
       };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a more complete picture of your code it's hard to say what exactly is wrong, but you are probably missing a lifetime specifier on your `impl`. For example, this code will compile:

```rust
pub struct A<'a> {
    pub f: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn new(t: &'a str) -> Self {
        A {
             f: t,
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    A::new("hi");
}
```

You need to implement A for the generic lifetime `'a`, otherwise the compiler will imply the `'static` lifetime which conflicts with your struct definition.

This in most cases isn't very practical however, and you *probably* want your struct to hold a string using the [String](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) type instead which has ownership over the string rather than a reference.